# How to map json keys which include dots?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json in which some of its keys include dots.
for example:

```
{
    "key.1" : 10,
    "key.2" : 20,
    "key.3" : 30
}
```

I was planning to use Jackson to map it into a MyClass model object using something like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass obj = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class
```

Of course I cannot create class members with dots in their names.

So, is there a way to overcome this situation?

Jackson is preferred but not mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the annotation `@JsonProperty` on top of the field declaration, with a name that is different than the field's name:

```
@JsonProperty("key.1")
private final int key1;
@JsonProperty("key.2")
private final int key2;
@JsonProperty("key.3")
private final int key3;
```

As a general note, Jackson will map the Json key to the field name *only if you don't specify anything else* (so it will go by reflection).
However, with Jackson is possible to modify the names of the fields (and not only) using their annotations.

As a side note, you'll also need to annotate the constructor parameters to deserialize the object from Json to Java object:

```
@JsonCreator
public MyClass(
    @JsonProperty(value = "key.1", required = true) int key1,
    @JsonProperty(value = "key.2", required = true) int key2,
    @JsonProperty(value = "key.3", required = true) int key3) {
    this.key1 = key1;
    this.key2 = key2;
    this.key3 = key3;
}
```

... then you will be able to do what you wanted:

```
MyClass obj = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: Join the post above, I will add only that when using Gson you should use SerializedName annotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will soon try your suggestion, and if it will be working for me I'll gladly accept it as an answer.

Comment: @Matteo NNZ I cannot find JsonConstructor annotation. Did you mean JsonCreator annotaion?

Comment: @dushkin yes sorry,  I meant that annotation. I'll fix my post